# After installing Steam through PlayOnLinux, do I install the windows games through Steam or PlayOnLinux?

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is setup and running smoothly.

I want to play Windows Steam games on Ubuntu. I installed PlayOnLinux and then installed Steam through that. The installation went perfectly, but now I'm stuck. I don't know if I am supposed to install my Steam games through Steam after launching it through PlayonLinux or install them using just PlayOnLinux?

Thanks and sorry for the long message, Good day.

Comment: Any specific reason why you installed Steam through PlayOnLinux? `sudo apt-get install steam` would install the native steam client.

Comment: @MadMike I believe the OP wants *to play Windows Steam games on Ubuntu*

Comment: @mchid I can imagine many good reason to install Steam via POL. But to give a good answer I wanted to know the *specific* reason (I.e. which game) why he did so.

Answer (score 1):

For running windows only games, you can startup wine from playonlinux and install them from steam.

Although, you can usually install games directly from playonlinux as well.